# Angular .map and .subscribe yield funny arrays?

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, rxjs, subscribe

Cannot figure out the following behaviour. Nor remember having come across something similar in the past. I have to admit that I'm new to angular and RxJS, but hey!

```
this.service.getAll().map( r => {
    console.log(r)         // Array of 40 elements. Fine.
    console.log(r.length)  // Says "0"!
    return r.map( x => x)  // What happens here?
}).subscribe( r => {
    console.log([])        // That's what an empty array looks like.
    console.log(r)         // Empty!
})
```

1) Why is length of a viable array zero?
2) Why does array.map( x => x) sink my dear array elements?

Eagerly awaiting hints.

Comment: `map` is usually used to iterate an array, so `r` here is likely each element of the array, so an array element normally does not have a length, unless it's another array, (multi-dimensional).  If remove the `.map` and then what does `r.length` equal?

Comment: Are you talking about Array.map or Observalble.map? If about Array.map, then see I log length of the raw array as it enters the closure.

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is an operator used on observables to transform the data and it also returns an observable.

1. I am not sure whether the array you are outputting in console is wrapped under some key or not.. Becuase if its length is 0 then definitely it is not an array. You might need to look closely.
2. You might try to use `.json()` on the response, which might give you the actual response you are expecting.
3. `r.map( x => x)` is not doing anything here. It is `Array.map` which returning the element without modifying it.

Here in your case you do not need to use .map() on the observable, instead you can just do this:

```
this.service.getAll()
  .subscribe( r => {
     console.log(r);
     // See how r looks like here       
  })
```

Comment: 1) It's an array with elements, 2) It's already parsed in my service instance, 3) I know, I put the .map( x=> x) just for illustration. I'll have a look at my service, just a moment...

Comment: The code I posted is fine. Bad rx code in my service was the culprit! I will post the solution in a minute. +1 for channeling my thoughts in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The code in the original question was fine. The strange effects I mentioned were caused by a (probably) bad construct in my service class, which looked something like this:

```
getAll(): Observable<MyObject[]> {

    let o$ = this.http.post("serviceURL/getAll", "{}")
    let newArr = []
    o$.subscribe( r => {

        let arr = r["payload"]  // taking what's of interest

        // now create objects not directly conforming to json
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            let json = arr[i]
            let newObject = new MyObject()
            newObject.parseAndStuff(json)
            newArray.push(newObject)
        }
    })
    // Didn't know how to apply the correct rx operators.
    return of(newArr)
}
```

Note the approach of creating a new array in the function scope and returning an observable thereof, and adding objects to it in the closure. This seems to work once (or more?) if you don't touch things as I did in the original post.

Still, I cannot explain the funny behaviour, but resolved it. Feel free to explain it! Cheers.